# unable to initialized namenode ,datanode,jobtracker,tasktracker in cenos

Tags: hadoop

when i give the command

```
for service in /etc/init.d/hadoop*
>do
>sudo $service stop
>done
its stops all the service
```

and when i give

```
for service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*
>do
>sudo $service stop
>done
```

its stops all the service 
it sometimes start datanode and sometimes namenode
eg:

```
21270 NameNode
21422 Jps
21374 SecondaryNameNode
2624 HMaster
```

or

```
11070 DataNode
11422 Jps
11554 SecondaryNameNode
2554 HMaster
```

same thing happens for jobtracker and tasktracker

I tried formating the namenode but it didnt help

I also changing the path of localhost in

```
core-site.xml from 8020 to 50020
and also in mapred-site.xml from 8021 to 50020
```

this time it shows NameNode, DataNode, JobTracker,Tasktracker using jps

but when i check the browser `localhost:50070 and localhost:50030`
it refers to 8020 instead of 50020.
 why is this happening ?
please help

Comment: Show your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Run the following script from terminal to stop the running hadoop daemons.

```
> $HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
```

Run the following script from terminal to start the hadoop daemons.

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh